# Dell M6600: "No internet access", can browse internet, can remote into it, cannot activate office 2013, cannot join domain

Tags: networking, windows-7, windows

Like the title says, I've got a Dell M6600, running Windows 7, that connects to the network just fine, I can use it to browse the web, including https://officesetup.getmicrosoftkey.com/, I can connect to it via RDP, it was joined to the domain (more below), no noticeable slowness in the network connection. The issue is that the active networks are reporting Access Type: No internet access, and I can't connect to *some* things, like I can't activate Office 2013 because "We are unable to connect right now. Please check your network and try again later". No software firewall is enabled.

Here's what I've tried:

- `ipconfig release & ipconfig renew`
- run `netsh int ip reset c:\temp\resetlog.txt` (the log never gets generated)
- Connect with Wired Ethernet only
- Connect with WiFi only
- Uninstall/reinstall the network adapters using the management console
- Wade through a swath of unhelpful google results like `route delete 0.0.0.0 if 11`
- Attempt a domain rejoin, got as far as removing the computer from the domain, but can't readd, as "The network location cannot be reached" (I can still RDP to it at this point using local creds, there are gpupdate failure events that should've told me this would fail)
- Check NCSI issues: navigation to http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt in IE results in a page with the text: "Microsoft NCSI", dns.msftncsi.com resolves correctly
- Pinging the DNS server results in request timed out, but performing nslookup works just fine using said DNS server.
- changed the IP address of the DHCP reservation to a known unused IP address to check for IP address conflicts
- uninstalled AV software
- changing switch port, switch for wired access had no effect, Dynamic Address Tables correctly updated when switched to a different port (the ports on the switches have the same configurations for most of the other successfully communicating computers on the network)
- pinging DNS server works now, was failing, even though it was working fine with nslookup when pinging

(computer/domain names redacted in the following, some truncated for brevity)
ipconfig /all:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : computer
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : contoso.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : contoso.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D0-67-E5-2F-D2-20
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.2.240(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, December 03, 2014 10:11:41 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, December 05, 2014 10:14:57 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.2.22
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.2.22
                                       172.17.2.21
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 172.17.2.22
   Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 172.17.2.24
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

route print: (normal, removed to post wireshark)

wireshark with filter `bootp.option.dhcp` during `ipconfig /renew & ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew`:

```
No.     Time           Source                Source Port Destination           Destination Port Protocol Length Info
   1265 54.049678000   172.17.2.100          68          172.17.2.22           67               DHCP     348    DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0xd64657df

Frame 1265: 348 bytes on wire (2784 bits), 348 bytes captured (2784 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20), Dst: Dell_5e:94:e3 (84:2b:2b:5e:94:e3)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100), Dst: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
Bootstrap Protocol (Request)
    Message type: Boot Request (1)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0xd64657df
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
    Your (client) IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (Request)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: Request (3)
    Option: (61) Client identifier
        Length: 7
        Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
        Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Option: (12) Host Name
        Length: 11
        Host Name: computer
    Option: (81) Client Fully Qualified Domain Name
        Length: 14
        Flags: 0x00
        0000 .... = Reserved flags: 0x00
        .... 0... = Server DDNS: Some server updates
        .... .0.. = Encoding: ASCII encoding
        .... ..0. = Server overrides: No override
        .... ...0 = Server: Client
        A-RR result: 0
        PTR-RR result: 0
        Client name: computer
    Option: (60) Vendor class identifier
        Length: 8
        Vendor class identifier: MSFT 5.0
    Option: (55) Parameter Request List
        Length: 12
        Parameter Request List Item: (1) Subnet Mask
        Parameter Request List Item: (15) Domain Name
        Parameter Request List Item: (3) Router
        Parameter Request List Item: (6) Domain Name Server
        Parameter Request List Item: (44) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server
        Parameter Request List Item: (46) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type
        Parameter Request List Item: (47) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Scope
        Parameter Request List Item: (31) Perform Router Discover
        Parameter Request List Item: (33) Static Route
        Parameter Request List Item: (121) Classless Static Route
        Parameter Request List Item: (249) Private/Classless Static Route (Microsoft)
        Parameter Request List Item: (43) Vendor-Specific Information
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255

No.     Time           Source                Source Port Destination           Destination Port Protocol Length Info
   1268 54.050521000   172.17.2.22           67          172.17.2.100          68               DHCP     381    DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0xd64657df

Frame 1268: 381 bytes on wire (3048 bits), 381 bytes captured (3048 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_5e:94:e3 (84:2b:2b:5e:94:e3), Dst: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22), Dst: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
Bootstrap Protocol (ACK)
    Message type: Boot Reply (2)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0xd64657df
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Your (client) IP address: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
    Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (ACK)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: ACK (5)
    Option: (58) Renewal Time Value
        Length: 4
        Renewal Time Value: (86400s) 1 day
    Option: (59) Rebinding Time Value
        Length: 4
        Rebinding Time Value: (151200s) 1 day, 18 hours
    Option: (51) IP Address Lease Time
        Length: 4
        IP Address Lease Time: (172800s) 2 days
    Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
        Length: 4
        DHCP Server Identifier: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
    Option: (1) Subnet Mask
        Length: 4
        Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 (255.255.255.0)
    Option: (81) Client Fully Qualified Domain Name
        Length: 3
        Flags: 0x00
        0000 .... = Reserved flags: 0x00
        .... 0... = Server DDNS: Some server updates
        .... .0.. = Encoding: ASCII encoding
        .... ..0. = Server overrides: No override
        .... ...0 = Server: Client
        A-RR result: 255
        PTR-RR result: 255
    Option: (15) Domain Name
        Length: 9
        Domain Name: contoso.com
    Option: (3) Router
        Length: 4
        Router: 172.17.2.1 (172.17.2.1)
    Option: (6) Domain Name Server
        Length: 8
        Domain Name Server: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
        Domain Name Server: 172.17.2.21 (172.17.2.21)
    Option: (44) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server
        Length: 8
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server: 172.17.2.24 (172.17.2.24)
    Option: (46) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type
        Length: 1
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type: H-node (8)
    Option: (121) Classless Static Route
        Length: 8
        Subnet/MaskWidth-Router: 172.17.3.0/24-172.17.2.2
    Option: (249) Private/Classless Static Route (Microsoft)
        Length: 8
        Subnet/MaskWidth-Router: 172.17.3.0/24-172.17.2.2
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255

No.     Time           Source                Source Port Destination           Destination Port Protocol Length Info
   1280 54.115690000   172.17.2.100          68          172.17.2.22           67               DHCP     342    DHCP Release  - Transaction ID 0x18a9cba3

Frame 1280: 342 bytes on wire (2736 bits), 342 bytes captured (2736 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20), Dst: Dell_5e:94:e3 (84:2b:2b:5e:94:e3)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100), Dst: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
Bootstrap Protocol (Release)
    Message type: Boot Request (1)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0x18a9cba3
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
    Your (client) IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (Release)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: Release (7)
    Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
        Length: 4
        DHCP Server Identifier: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
    Option: (61) Client identifier
        Length: 7
        Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
        Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255
    Padding

No.     Time           Source                Source Port Destination           Destination Port Protocol Length Info
   1372 59.175867000   0.0.0.0               68          255.255.255.255       67               DHCP     342    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x97a2aa5c

Frame 1372: 342 bytes on wire (2736 bits), 342 bytes captured (2736 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
    Message type: Boot Request (1)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0x97a2aa5c
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Your (client) IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (Discover)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: Discover (1)
    Option: (61) Client identifier
        Length: 7
        Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
        Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Option: (50) Requested IP Address
        Length: 4
        Requested IP Address: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
    Option: (12) Host Name
        Length: 11
        Host Name: computer
    Option: (60) Vendor class identifier
        Length: 8
        Vendor class identifier: MSFT 5.0
    Option: (55) Parameter Request List
        Length: 12
        Parameter Request List Item: (1) Subnet Mask
        Parameter Request List Item: (15) Domain Name
        Parameter Request List Item: (3) Router
        Parameter Request List Item: (6) Domain Name Server
        Parameter Request List Item: (44) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server
        Parameter Request List Item: (46) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type
        Parameter Request List Item: (47) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Scope
        Parameter Request List Item: (31) Perform Router Discover
        Parameter Request List Item: (33) Static Route
        Parameter Request List Item: (121) Classless Static Route
        Parameter Request List Item: (249) Private/Classless Static Route (Microsoft)
        Parameter Request List Item: (43) Vendor-Specific Information
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255
    Padding

No.     Time           Source                Source Port Destination           Destination Port Protocol Length Info
   1373 59.176223000   172.17.2.22           67          255.255.255.255       68               DHCP     376    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x97a2aa5c

Frame 1373: 376 bytes on wire (3008 bits), 376 bytes captured (3008 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_5e:94:e3 (84:2b:2b:5e:94:e3), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
    Message type: Boot Reply (2)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0x97a2aa5c
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Your (client) IP address: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
    Next server IP address: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (Offer)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: Offer (2)
    Option: (1) Subnet Mask
        Length: 4
        Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 (255.255.255.0)
    Option: (58) Renewal Time Value
        Length: 4
        Renewal Time Value: (86400s) 1 day
    Option: (59) Rebinding Time Value
        Length: 4
        Rebinding Time Value: (151200s) 1 day, 18 hours
    Option: (51) IP Address Lease Time
        Length: 4
        IP Address Lease Time: (172800s) 2 days
    Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
        Length: 4
        DHCP Server Identifier: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
    Option: (15) Domain Name
        Length: 9
        Domain Name: contoso.com
    Option: (3) Router
        Length: 4
        Router: 172.17.2.1 (172.17.2.1)
    Option: (6) Domain Name Server
        Length: 8
        Domain Name Server: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
        Domain Name Server: 172.17.2.21 (172.17.2.21)
    Option: (44) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server
        Length: 8
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server: 172.17.2.24 (172.17.2.24)
    Option: (46) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type
        Length: 1
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type: H-node (8)
    Option: (121) Classless Static Route
        Length: 8
        Subnet/MaskWidth-Router: 172.17.3.0/24-172.17.2.2
    Option: (249) Private/Classless Static Route (Microsoft)
        Length: 8
        Subnet/MaskWidth-Router: 172.17.3.0/24-172.17.2.2
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255

No.     Time           Source                Source Port Destination           Destination Port Protocol Length Info
   1374 59.176534000   0.0.0.0               68          255.255.255.255       67               DHCP     360    DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x97a2aa5c

Frame 1374: 360 bytes on wire (2880 bits), 360 bytes captured (2880 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
Bootstrap Protocol (Request)
    Message type: Boot Request (1)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0x97a2aa5c
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Your (client) IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (Request)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: Request (3)
    Option: (61) Client identifier
        Length: 7
        Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
        Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Option: (50) Requested IP Address
        Length: 4
        Requested IP Address: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
    Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
        Length: 4
        DHCP Server Identifier: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
    Option: (12) Host Name
        Length: 11
        Host Name: computer
    Option: (81) Client Fully Qualified Domain Name
        Length: 14
        Flags: 0x00
        0000 .... = Reserved flags: 0x00
        .... 0... = Server DDNS: Some server updates
        .... .0.. = Encoding: ASCII encoding
        .... ..0. = Server overrides: No override
        .... ...0 = Server: Client
        A-RR result: 0
        PTR-RR result: 0
        Client name: computer
    Option: (60) Vendor class identifier
        Length: 8
        Vendor class identifier: MSFT 5.0
    Option: (55) Parameter Request List
        Length: 12
        Parameter Request List Item: (1) Subnet Mask
        Parameter Request List Item: (15) Domain Name
        Parameter Request List Item: (3) Router
        Parameter Request List Item: (6) Domain Name Server
        Parameter Request List Item: (44) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server
        Parameter Request List Item: (46) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type
        Parameter Request List Item: (47) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Scope
        Parameter Request List Item: (31) Perform Router Discover
        Parameter Request List Item: (33) Static Route
        Parameter Request List Item: (121) Classless Static Route
        Parameter Request List Item: (249) Private/Classless Static Route (Microsoft)
        Parameter Request List Item: (43) Vendor-Specific Information
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255

No.     Time           Source                Source Port Destination           Destination Port Protocol Length Info
   1375 59.177078000   172.17.2.22           67          255.255.255.255       68               DHCP     381    DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x97a2aa5c

Frame 1375: 381 bytes on wire (3048 bits), 381 bytes captured (3048 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_5e:94:e3 (84:2b:2b:5e:94:e3), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
Bootstrap Protocol (ACK)
    Message type: Boot Reply (2)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0x97a2aa5c
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Your (client) IP address: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
    Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (ACK)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: ACK (5)
    Option: (58) Renewal Time Value
        Length: 4
        Renewal Time Value: (86400s) 1 day
    Option: (59) Rebinding Time Value
        Length: 4
        Rebinding Time Value: (151200s) 1 day, 18 hours
    Option: (51) IP Address Lease Time
        Length: 4
        IP Address Lease Time: (172800s) 2 days
    Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
        Length: 4
        DHCP Server Identifier: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
    Option: (1) Subnet Mask
        Length: 4
        Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 (255.255.255.0)
    Option: (81) Client Fully Qualified Domain Name
        Length: 3
        Flags: 0x00
        0000 .... = Reserved flags: 0x00
        .... 0... = Server DDNS: Some server updates
        .... .0.. = Encoding: ASCII encoding
        .... ..0. = Server overrides: No override
        .... ...0 = Server: Client
        A-RR result: 255
        PTR-RR result: 255
    Option: (15) Domain Name
        Length: 9
        Domain Name: contoso.com
    Option: (3) Router
        Length: 4
        Router: 172.17.2.1 (172.17.2.1)
    Option: (6) Domain Name Server
        Length: 8
        Domain Name Server: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
        Domain Name Server: 172.17.2.21 (172.17.2.21)
    Option: (44) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server
        Length: 8
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server: 172.17.2.24 (172.17.2.24)
    Option: (46) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type
        Length: 1
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type: H-node (8)
    Option: (121) Classless Static Route
        Length: 8
        Subnet/MaskWidth-Router: 172.17.3.0/24-172.17.2.2
    Option: (249) Private/Classless Static Route (Microsoft)
        Length: 8
        Subnet/MaskWidth-Router: 172.17.3.0/24-172.17.2.2
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255

No.     Time           Source                Source Port Destination           Destination Port Protocol Length Info
   1431 62.210304000   172.17.2.100          68          255.255.255.255       67               DHCP     342    DHCP Inform   - Transaction ID 0xd46e0a9b

Frame 1431: 342 bytes on wire (2736 bits), 342 bytes captured (2736 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
Bootstrap Protocol (Inform)
    Message type: Boot Request (1)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0xd46e0a9b
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
    Your (client) IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (Inform)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: Inform (8)
    Option: (61) Client identifier
        Length: 7
        Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
        Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Option: (12) Host Name
        Length: 11
        Host Name: computer
    Option: (60) Vendor class identifier
        Length: 8
        Vendor class identifier: MSFT 5.0
    Option: (55) Parameter Request List
        Length: 13
        Parameter Request List Item: (1) Subnet Mask
        Parameter Request List Item: (15) Domain Name
        Parameter Request List Item: (3) Router
        Parameter Request List Item: (6) Domain Name Server
        Parameter Request List Item: (44) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server
        Parameter Request List Item: (46) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type
        Parameter Request List Item: (47) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Scope
        Parameter Request List Item: (31) Perform Router Discover
        Parameter Request List Item: (33) Static Route
        Parameter Request List Item: (121) Classless Static Route
        Parameter Request List Item: (249) Private/Classless Static Route (Microsoft)
        Parameter Request List Item: (43) Vendor-Specific Information
        Parameter Request List Item: (252) Private/Proxy autodiscovery
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255
    Padding

No.     Time           Source                Source Port Destination           Destination Port Protocol Length Info
   1432 62.210721000   172.17.2.22           67          172.17.2.100          68               DHCP     365    DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0xd46e0a9b

Frame 1432: 365 bytes on wire (2920 bits), 365 bytes captured (2920 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Dell_5e:94:e3 (84:2b:2b:5e:94:e3), Dst: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22), Dst: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
Bootstrap Protocol (ACK)
    Message type: Boot Reply (2)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0xd46e0a9b
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 172.17.2.100 (172.17.2.100)
    Your (client) IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Dell_2f:d2:20 (d0:67:e5:2f:d2:20)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (ACK)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: ACK (5)
    Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
        Length: 4
        DHCP Server Identifier: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
    Option: (1) Subnet Mask
        Length: 4
        Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 (255.255.255.0)
    Option: (43) Vendor-Specific Information
        Length: 5
        Value: dc034e4150
    Option: (15) Domain Name
        Length: 9
        Domain Name: contoso.com
    Option: (3) Router
        Length: 4
        Router: 172.17.2.1 (172.17.2.1)
    Option: (6) Domain Name Server
        Length: 8
        Domain Name Server: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
        Domain Name Server: 172.17.2.21 (172.17.2.21)
    Option: (44) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server
        Length: 8
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server: 172.17.2.22 (172.17.2.22)
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server: 172.17.2.24 (172.17.2.24)
    Option: (46) NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type
        Length: 1
        NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type: H-node (8)
    Option: (121) Classless Static Route
        Length: 8
        Subnet/MaskWidth-Router: 172.17.3.0/24-172.17.2.2
    Option: (249) Private/Classless Static Route (Microsoft)
        Length: 8
        Subnet/MaskWidth-Router: 172.17.3.0/24-172.17.2.2
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255
```

Comment: Wow, this is broad.  I can only add a list of things to check off the top of my head: DHCP (the actual response, wireshark it), firewall (local and network), the switch (acls, switchport, etc), antivirus software, duplicate IPs on the subnet, your routing table, and the phase of the moon over Redmond.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, nslookup uses it's own DNS resolver, so testing resolution of dns.msftncsi.com with nslookup may be a bit of a red herring. Flush the DNS server cache and flush your DNS client cache and ping dns.msftncsi.com and see if it resolves correctly.

Comment: Pinging dns.msftncsi.com resolves to 131.107.255.255

Comment: Can you add other machines to your domain successfully? Why does ping to your DNS server fail? Have you firewalled more ports than you should have to your domain controllers?

Comment: @mfinni, I don't know why ping was failing, it's working on other machines hooked up to the same switch, both before and after adding them to the domain. Testing again, ping is working fine now.

Comment: Is windows still activated? Try connecting to your volume activation server and verify everything is ok there. I assume you have more than this one computer in your domain and all the other ones are working. At this point I would reimage the machine.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm going to do. It's just annoying because I just imaged that machine 4 weeks ago and it hasn't gotten much use in the meantime.

Comment: Re-imaging the machine did restore network connectivity, but also exposed an issue with the CPU overheating. Cleaning out the heat sinks seems to have fixed that issue on this machine, though I have no idea if the thermal issues have anything to do with this or if they were purely coincidental.

Comment: Issue returned after machine rebooted in a non-clean fashion after driver installation. End result is now warranty repair/replacement of the machine.

Comment: Machine came back. Issue returned after installing the OEM provided WiFi driver. (Dell Precision M6600 with Intel WiFi) Installing the driver from Intel resulted in correct functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be driver related. (DOH! I forgot to try a different driver version when uninstalling and re-installing the drivers.)

The OEM drivers caused the machine to have the "no internet access" symptom, and using a driver straight from Intel resulted in the system functioning correctly. The system is a Dell M6600 with an Intel 6200 WiFi card. The issue returned after I installed the WiFi driver from Dell, and I had to do a system restore to get the issue to revert, then install the driver from Intel, and the WiFi worked, as well as everything else.

Thank you everyone for the excellent suggestions!

Comment: Well, that doesn't make much sense.  I suspect that in the course of reinstalling your drivers, something else was fixed.  In any case, glad to hear you got it working.

Comment: Right, but the issue reappeared after the system was reimaged and the mobo was replaced. There was nothing preserved from the previous configuration, nothing special done to this system, it's just that installing that particular driver caused the issue to happen. I even installed each driver one by one, restarting the system between each driver installation after putting a fresh image on the machine, (yes, a tedious process, but I wanted to prove that that was the issue and that the driver change wasn't just masking some other issue), and that was the best conclusion I could come up with.

Answer (score 7):

Dealing specifically with the "No Internet Access" message, Windows uses NCSI (Network Connectivity Status Indicator) for this.  This checks two things:

1. A request for http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt -
   Page called ncsi.txt containing the following line of text with no terminating new line or other non-printing characters:  Microsoft NCSI
2. A request for DNS name resolution of dns.msftncsi.com -
   Resolution of the DNS name to: 131.107.255.255

If either of these fail, you get the "No Internet Access" message.  I would *guess* that Office isn't even trying to register at this stage, you're getting a stock message based on NCSI having failed.  I'd fix the NCSI issue first then try and register Office again.

Comment: Testing those two work as expected. Adding this to test steps.

Comment: Just to say, `dns.msftncsi.com` doesn't seem to respond to pings, so if you try `ping dns.msftncsi.com`, it should successfully resolve the IP if it's working properly, even if the actual pings fail.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar issue with a couple of users with admin rights on their machines (developers) who were setting up their machines, including installing Office 2013.  One connected to his home network and activated Office that way, while the other contacted me.

Our small office uses a Watchguard router that includes a proxy server that requires no settings on the user end.  I added "allow range requests through unmodified," to no avail.  I then told Watchguard not to proxy that user at all.  But because his install had previously failed, I had to wander around his hard drive and registry deleting stuff before I could get it to work.

I know you said in reply to one of Massimo's answers that there's no proxy for the network, but it might be worth double-checking if you're not 100% certain.

Comment: That's curious. We've got a Firebox XTM 515 serving as a gateway for this machine, as well as the other machines I've successfully added to the domain and activated Office 2013 on. The Firebox is set up to proxy HTTP(s) traffic only, and pass the rest through unmolested. When I try to activate office, I don't see any connection logs on the Firebox, but do when I browse the web. I'm guessing either the connection is never attempted or the activation service uses another port. It only logs connections that match policies.

Answer (score 2):

A different answer, probably not your case, but it's worth a shot: you said "no software firewall is enabled", so I'm assuming this include Windows Firewall too; but how did you disable it?

If you by chance disabled it by *actually stopping the Windows Firewall service*, then you must re-enable it immediately. That's not the proper way to disable the system firewall, and leads to all sort of weird networking problems (see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/520509/how-can-i-back-up-my-recommendation-to-not-disable-the-windows-firewall-service) for a discussion). You can configure it to not block anything, but you should *never* actually stop the Windows Firewall service, which is a critical component of the networking stack in 6.0 and later Windows systems.

Comment: Disabled it when it was connected to the domain by GPO, when off the domain by setting the firewall state to off in the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security console.

Comment: This is fine, but make sure the "Windows Firewall" service is running even if the firewall is actually disabled.

Comment: it's definitely running :)

Answer (score 1):

As you mention that the computer is joined to a domain, it is possible that there is a group policy setting a custom NCSI server instead of the default one from Microsoft. You should be able to see if there is a custom server defined by looking under

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet`

with the registry editor. There are different values that specify the server to use (both for DNS and HTTP test) and the expected results. If there is nothing unexpected there, a possibility would be that when you request http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt with a browser, you're going through a proxy that has access to Internet, while the computer doesn't. A network capture (e.g., with Wireshark) is often very useful to figure out many types of connectivity problems. Try to do a capture for some minutes, and check if you see any NCSI-related traffic and what the outcome is.

Another possibility might be that the *Network Location Awareness* service (in charge of the NCSI testing) is not running, although in this case I would not expect the system to say "No Internet Access".

Comment: Nope, not using a custom NCSI server. Also, the machine isn't domain joined anymore, (I removed it from the domain for testing purposes and can't re-add it because of its issues). Checked the key, all the values are still at their defaults. Also, the Network Location Awareness service is running.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention anything about a proxy, thus I'm assuming your network doesn't need one for Internet access; if this is the case, make sure you have no proxy configured in Internet Explorer, and *also* make sure you have no proxy configured for the system services; you can check this using the command `netsh winhttp dump`, and you can reset those settings to default (direct Internet access) using the command `netsh winhttp reset proxy`.

Comment: That's correct, there is neither a proxy for the network, nor is there one configured in IE or netsh winhttp dump

Answer (score 0):

Long shot answer but something to look at... I had a Windows Server 2012 VM that would say No Internet Connection, though I could browse the web just fine.  Could also ping and connect to M$ dns.msftcsi site without issue.

What I found cleared the No Internet message, was re-enabling IPv6, even though we only use v4.

Comment: Re-enabling as in it was disabled at the start of your troubleshooting? IPv6 was enabled on this machine at the start of my troubleshooting, and I disabled it as a troubleshooting step (that I forgot to record). I just re-enabled it now to test, but still have the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen weird things with mixed drivers. During the builds if your not using a deployment tool you can still install the Dell Driver packs directly from DOS and basically loop through the installation of all drivers. When you download the Driver Pack they also have a list on Dell's support site that lists if there's more current drivers available or known issues with devices. To install the driver pack from DOS check out the tutorial here: http://www.1337admin.org/tutorials/manual-installation-of-a-dell-driver-pack-on-a-local-machine/

Be sure to manually type the commands as certain characters get messed up between the clipboard and a webpage and DOS or PowerShell windows. I use this technique every time and it probably saves me a good 30-45 minutes each time.

Comment: For the copy/paste issues, I find it useful to copy/paste into a good text editor before copy/pasting into a command prompt, or just running the command as a script at that point. This allows me to catch the weird formatting issues (like “ ” instead of " and non-breaking spaces, etc) that can result from a web copy before execution, and reduces copy-by-typing errors resulting from sloppy keyboarding/reading.